# Valuebox like function for static reports

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I really like the clean look of R's [valueboxes](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#value_boxes) in flexdashboards and shinydashboards:

[image]

Is there a package, or a recipe using familiar tools (i.e. `ggplot2`) to easily produce similar output for a static report? For example, in a PDF document knitted from RMarkdown

**EDIT:**

After a few tries I got something usable using ggplot2 (answer below). Other answers welcome!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I extended HAVB's answer to make the appearance more like valueboxes by using the [Emojifont R package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/emojifont/index.html).

Below is the code modified from HAVB's answer including a mix of font-awesome icons and emojis. I also broke up the text parts into the large (`value`) and small (`info`) text so that I could size them differently.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(emojifont)
df <- data.frame(
    x = rep(seq(2, 15, 6.5), 2),
    y = c(rep(6.5, 3), rep(2,3)),
    h = rep(4.25, 6),
    w = rep(6.25, 6),
    value = c("78%",
             "+10K",
             "8/10",
             "ALL",
             "6",
             "< 0.5"),
    info = c("meaningless plots",
             "hours wasted",
             "zombies prefer brains",
             "dogs go to heaven",
             "infoboxes",
             "target pvalue"),
    icon = c(fontawesome(search_fontawesome("chart")),
             emoji("athletic_shoe")),
    font_family = c(rep("fontawesome-webfont", 5),
                    "EmojiOne"),
    color = factor(1:6)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, height = h, width = w, label = info)) +
    ## Create the tiles using the `color` column
    geom_tile(aes(fill = color)) +
    ## Add the numeric values as text in `value` column
    geom_text(color = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 10,
              aes(label = value, x = x - 2.9, y = y + 1), hjust = 0) +
    ## Add the labels for each box stored in the `info` column
    geom_text(color = "white", fontface = "bold",
              aes(label = info, x = x - 2.9, y = y - 1), hjust = 0) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual",palette = "Dark2") +
    ## Use `geom_text()` to add the icons by specifying the unicode symbol.
    geom_text(size = 20, aes(label = icon, family = font_family,
                             x = x + 1.5, y = y + 0.5), alpha = 0.25) +
    theme_void() +
    guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image: resulting plot]

I think the result is quite nice and could be further improved to be more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: these are great answers but it would be good to explain more the code in the answer. It would be great to understand what is going on with shape and font_family as an example as well as some other things done with so many geom_text() lines

Comment: I updated the answer to provide explanation of the key plotting lines in the comments.

Answer (score 9):

`ggplot2`'s `geom_tile` can be used to make colorful rectangles, and then `geom_text` to add the labels/info. The solution is clunky compared with the ease of using `infobox` / `valuebox` in `shiny`, but it will do.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
    x = rep(seq(2, 15, 6.5), 2),
    y = c(rep(2,3), rep(6.5, 3)),
    h = rep(4, 6),
    w = rep(6, 6),
    info = c("78%\nmeaningless plots",
             "+10K\nhours wasted",
             "8/10\nzombies prefer brains",
             "ALL\ndogs go to heaven",
             "6\ninfoboxes",
             "< 0.5\ntarget pvalue"),
    color = factor(1:6)
)


ggplot(df, aes(x, y, height = h, width = w, label = info, fill = color)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(color = "white", fontface = "bold") +
    coord_fixed() + 
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual",palette = "Dark2") +
    theme_void() +
    guides(fill = F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I created a function to make the code from @StefanAvey more portable.

I put it on GitHub in a [repository](https://github.com/monkeywithacupcake/legendary-succotash/blob/main/createValueBoxGrid.R), so anyone can make it better.

Right now, the height and width of the boxes, padding between them, and the number of rows are arguments.

There are a few things I have not implemented, like treatment for rows of unequal length.

```
createValueBoxes <- function(df, h = 4, w = 6, padding=0.5, rows = 2){
  # required packages
  library(ggplot2)
  library(emojifont)
  # verify our inputs
  if (!is.data.frame(df)) {
    stop(paste("Argument", deparse(substitute(df)), "must be a data.frame."))
    }
  if(!all(i <- rlang::has_name(df,c("values", "infos", "icons")))){
    stop(sprintf(
      "%s does not contain: %s",
      deparse(substitute(df)),
      paste(columns[!i], collapse=", ")))
  }
  
  boxes = nrow(df) # number of items passed
  # calculate the grid
  cols = boxes/rows
  plotdf <- data.frame(
    x = rep(seq(0, (w+padding)*cols-1, w+padding), times=rows),
    y = rep(seq(0, (h+padding)*rows-1, h+padding), each=cols),
    h = rep(h, boxes),
    w = rep(w, boxes),
    value = df$values,
    info = df$infos,
    icon = fontawesome(df$icons),
    font_family = c(rep("fontawesome-webfont", boxes)),
    color = factor(1:boxes)
  )
  print(plotdf)
  ggplot(plotdf, aes(x, y, height = h, width = w, label = info)) +
    ## Create the tiles using the `color` column
    geom_tile(aes(fill = color)) +
    ## Add the numeric values as text in `value` column
    geom_text(color = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 10,
              aes(label = value, x = x - w/2.2, y = y + h/4), hjust = 0) +
    ## Add the labels for each box stored in the `info` column
    geom_text(color = "white", fontface = "bold",
              aes(label = info, x = x - w/2.2, y = y-h/4), hjust = 0) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual",palette = "Dark2") +
    ## Use `geom_text()` to add the icons by specifying the unicode symbol.
    geom_text(size = 20, aes(label = icon, family = font_family,
                             x = x + w/4, y = y + h/8), alpha = 0.25) +
    theme_void() +
    guides(fill = FALSE)
  
}
```

It would be called like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
values=c("50%", "7", "1245"), 
infos=c("now", "super", "hours"), 
icons=c("fa-gear", "fa-diamond", "fa-tasks")
)
createValueBoxes(df, rows=1)
```

The result from this example is:
[image: 3 value boxes]

Answer (score 2):

Extending your solution to display a data frame using your design in the same arrangement as it would print to the console:

The data frame:

```
    mydata = data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        x2 = c(9,8,7,6,5),
                        label = c("description a",
                                  "description b",
                                  "description c",
                                  "description d",
                                  "description e"))
```

Intended to display as:

```
1  9 description a
2  8 description b
3  7 description c
4  6 description d
5  5 description e
```

Done with the following:

```
ht = 3
wd1 = 3
wd2 = 9
gap = 0.5
nc = ncol(mydata)
nr = nrow(mydata)

x = rep(c(seq(0,(nc-2)*(wd1+gap), wd1+gap), (nc-2)*(wd1+gap) + gap + 0.5*(wd2+wd1)), nr)
y = rep(seq(0,(nr-1)*(ht+gap), ht+gap), nc) %>% sort()
h = rep(ht, nr * nc)
w = rep(c(rep(wd1, nc-1), wd2), nr)
info = as.vector(t(as.matrix(mydata[nr:1,])))

df = data.frame(x = x, y = y, h = h, w = w, info = info)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, height = h, width = w, label = info)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(color = "white", fontface = "bold") +
  coord_fixed() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual",palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = F)
```

With the following result:
[Resulting Valuebox-like plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiSuF.png)