# How to add flexdashboard style valueBox in Quarto?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard, quarto

I have a Quarto qmd file with the below code to display a valueBox.

````
---
title: "My Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dygraphs)
library(flexdashboard)
```

### Data

```{r}
valueBox("42", color = "yellow", icon = "fa-calendar", caption = "cases of soda")
```
````

---

The code is rendered as below without the valueBox being created.

[image]

---

Any thoughts on how to render the valueBox like it does below in rmd files?

[image]

Comment: According to https://quarto.org/docs/faq/rmarkdown.html support for `flexdashboard` is planned for quarto but not implemented yet.

Comment: Yes I've seen that. I was looking for a workaround to achieve the same.

Comment: Check out valuebox from the package bslib, this renders valueboxes in colors and with sparklines etc if so desired: https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/value-boxes.html

Comment: Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105282/valuebox-like-function-for-static-reports).

Answer (score 1):

[`valuebox`](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/components.html#value-boxes) is available as of Quarto 1.4.451. Within a row include a second code chunks for a second column. Implementation offers [access](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/components.html#icon-and-color) to bootstrap icons.

Add to a quarto document as follows:

````
---
title: "My Dashboard"
format: dashboard
---

Figure Sizes

```{r}
#| component: valuebox
#| title: "cases of soda"

list(
  icon = "calendar",
  color = "yellow",
  value = 42
)

```

```{r}
#| component: valuebox
#| title: "cases of soda"
list(
  icon = "calendar",
  color = "yellow",
  value = 42
)
```
````

Comment: Can the value be rendered dynamically based on UI input?